# MySQL вложенный запрос UPDATE SET

Tags: jquery, mysql, update

Мне нужно импортировать старую базу данных в новую. Старая база была спроектирована неправильно. В таблице есть поле под названием `gardenId` - внешний ключ с таблицы `garden`. Но хранится в поле `gardenId`, поле name с таблицы `garden`.
То есть база не нормализирована и хранит имя сущности, а не ключ к ней. Соответственно мне нужно это ситуацию исправить при помощи запроса, так как данных много. Нужно в поле `gardenId` таблицы поместить именно `id` с таблицы `garden`.

Вот как это примерно должно быть, но конечно этот запрос не работает:

```
UPDATE `growing` SET gardenId = (SELECT ID FROM `garden` WHERE name = gardenId)
```

Подскажите, как написать данный запрос правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что запрос должен выглядеть так:

```
 UPDATE `growing`, `garden` SET `growing`.`gardenId` = `garden`.`ID` WHERE `growing`.`gardenId` = `garden`.`name`
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
UPDATE
  growing
JOIN
  garden
ON
  growing.gardenId = garden.name
SET
  growing.gardenId = garden.gardenId
```